# Only allow zip file uploads

Tags: php

I have already made an upload form. But I want users to be able to upload .zip files and .rar files. I already have tried the following:

```
$ftp_server = "myserver";
$ftp_user_name = "myuser";
$ftp_user_pass = "mypass";
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$fileExt = explode('.', $filename);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
$destination_folder = "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/FilesUpload";
$destination_file = $destination_folder . "/" . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

$allowed = array('zip', 'rar');
if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {

//my upload code

}else {
    echo "You are not allowed to upload this file.";
}
```

It does not show any errors. It only enters inside the else. It also does this when I am uploading .zip files, I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: use `pathinfo` to get extension: `$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = $path_parts['extension'];`

Comment: `$fileExt = explode('.', $filename);` should produce a Warning. `$filename` variable does not exist in provided code. As far as I can see explode won't work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get file extension.

2.`$filename` is no where defined in your code, so it will give you warning as well as extension checking code will always fail.

Modify code like below:

```
$ftp_server = "myserver";
$ftp_user_name = "myuser";
$ftp_user_pass = "mypass";

$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

/*get file extension [*/
  $fileExt = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $fileExt = strtolower($fileExt);
/* ] */

$destination_folder = "/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/AbonneerProgrammas/FilesUpload";
$destination_file = $destination_folder . "/" . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

$allowed = array('zip', 'rar');

/*use $extension variable to check allowed or not [*/
if(in_array($fileExt, $allowed)) {

//my upload code

}else {
    echo "U mag dit type bestand niet uploaden.";
}
/* ] */
```

Comment: @JohanDelft  glad to help you:):).. Happy coding..:)